# SuiteCRM API v8: Login/Authentication for password grant not working

Tags: api, authentication, suitecrm

I am trying to use the password login for the V8 API.
Currently I am sending the following information to the /Api/access_token URL:

```
{
“grant_type”: “password”,
“client_id”: “e14c034b-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-6032411a7d9d”,
“client_secret”: “XXXXX”,
“username”: “outlookclient”,
“password”: “XXXX”
}
```

I am always getting the following error message:

```
{
“error”: “unknown_error”,
“message”: “The password is invalid: XXXX”
}
```

I have tried to send the password plain and as an MD5 hash: Both lead to the same result.
I have also tried it with existing and newly created users, both with the same result.
Passwords have also been checked multiple times and still with the same result.

I am currently trying this on Postman.

In general the API seems to be running fine, because my separate client_credentials authentication works fine.

Can you help me what else I can do to get it running?

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in previous versions where the Auth will only work if you send it as a `form` instead of a `JSON`.

Use the header

`content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

and

`accept: application/json` and send the params as form inputs:

`scope=&grant_type=password&client_id=f303f973-0232-3cb3-4484-5e506c358845&client_secret=superSecret&username=admin&password=adminisPas`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was one part of the story. The other one was that I had to set the user_hash in the database itself since this was not done by the UI. After changing to x-www-form-urlencoded and adding the user_hash in the database it is running smoothly.